# "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" whenever I try using this method

Tags: c#

```
public void SaveAll(int volume, int duration, string playing, int 
                        LBPindex, int LBSindex, string URL, int maximum)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("SaveDATA.bin", FileMode.Create);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.Default);
    sw.WriteLine("SETTINGS" + "|" + volume + "|" + duration + "|" + 
    playing + "|" + LBPindex + "|" + LBSindex + "|" + URL + "|" + 
    maximum);

    foreach (var item1 in Playlist.SavedPlaylists)
    {
        sw.Write("PLAYLIST" + "|" + item1.Name + "|");
        foreach (var item2 in item1.SavedSongs)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(item2.Path + "|" + item2.Title + "|" + 
            item2.Author + "|" + item2.Album + "|" + item2.Release + 
            "|" + item2.Genre + "|" + item2.Comment);
        }
    }
    sw.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

Im making an Music Player and this Method is being used everytime the user changes some things to either playlists, songs or anything at all.

The error occures everytime my Filestream tries to do something.

Comment: Maybe you don't have permission to create a file in the working directory of your program.  Check `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

Comment: can you add some better exception handling and tell us what the exact error message is..?

Answer (score 1):

You're not disposing your `FileStream` nor your `StreamWriter`.  So they're probably holding onto something... especially if an exception is thrown.

Wrap them both with `using` blocks.

Technically StreamWriter can take ownership and dispose of the `FileStream` but I prefer being explicit.

Also, you may want to ensure you're only performing this action once at a time.  A simple `lock(_myMutex) {}` around the whole thing will suffice.  Where `_myMutex` is `private static readonly _myMutex = new object();`

Another note: you want to make sure your file is writable. Applications are usually installed to `Program Files` which does not allow writing of files (without UAC/System).

Finally, if you have some other program (eg. Notepad) with this file open, it will hold a lock on it.  Some editors are better than others in this regard.  So make sure you close any programs that have the file open.

EDIT: full example added.

EDIT2: changed file path, make sure to close editors.

```
private static readonly _fileMutex = new object();

public void SaveAll(int volume, int duration, string playing, int 
                        LBPindex, int LBSindex, string URL, int maximum)
{
    lock (_fileMutex) 
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "SaveDATA.bin");
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.Default))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("SETTINGS" + "|" + volume + "|" + duration + "|" + playing + "|" + LBPindex + "|" + LBSindex + "|" + URL + "|" + maximum);

                foreach (var item1 in Playlist.SavedPlaylists)
                {
                    sw.Write("PLAYLIST" + "|" + item1.Name + "|");
                    foreach (var item2 in item1.SavedSongs)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(item2.Path + "|" + item2.Title + "|" + item2.Author + "|" + item2.Album + "|" + item2.Release + "|" + item2.Genre + "|" + item2.Comment);
                    }
                }
                sw.Close();
            }
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that the question really means "every time except the first" when it says "the error occurs every time", this is a very plausible explanation.

Comment: @BenVoigt good catch!  You're right.  The app is probably deployed to `C:\Program Files\...` which doesn't have write privileges.  Try changing the path of "SaveDATA.bin" to something writable.  I'll adjust my example to reflect this.

Comment: Thought of another scenario where a text editor might have the file open in the background. Otherwise the Program Files permission issue would only affect installs of the application not `F5` runs in the IDE. (not sure which were affected by the bug)